# cannot adding subfolders to svn?

Tags: svn

when I commited a subfolder to svn I got following message: 'xyz' is not under Version control. 
My Environment contains a Folder and a lot of subfolders which all added to cvs:
a/a
a/b
a/c
Now I would like to add a new subfoler to svn:
svn add a/d (d exists into filesystem)
Then I commited the subfolder 
svn ci -m 'init' a/d
and I got the message svn: 'd' is not under Version controll. 
What make I wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `svn status a/d` ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are only trying to commit 'a/d', when 'd' is a member of 'a', so 'a' must also be commited.

svn ci -m 'init' a a/d

Be aware this will commit any other changes under 'a'.